# How could I found the function definition in REPL?

Tags: clojure

After experiencing several times, finally, I got a function works. After a few tests, I believe I could put this function to the source code file. But now the function definition is a long way burred in the REPL. I tryed

```
(source my-function)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It only work on the functions in the lib.

So I have to scroll back, and search (within Cider-nrepl,Emacs).

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're function definition starts with `defn`, within Cider/Emacs, you can type `(defn` at the REPL and hit `M-p` (Meta-p or Esc-p). This will find any previous input to the REPL that started with `(defn`. Hitting `M-p` multiple times will allow you to go backwards through history, i.e. it will find all input starting with `(defn`.

This of course works also for all other input to the REPL.